# Space before \begin{customlabel} ... \end{customlabel}

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I've not been a Latex user for long now, so I'm still fairly new.
I'm trying to include part of my code. I found that using custom directories and captions work best for structuring my document how I want it. Even though creating custom captions works fine, it seems to create a very large gap to the Text before and after.

I've included the used code and all commands that seem to be related.
Furthermore, the pictures should show the problem.

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[code]{font=small}
\DeclareCaptionType{code}[Code-Abschnitt][Code-Abschnitt-Verzeichnis]
\start{document}
   \begin{code}
      \begin{lstlisting}[language={[Sharp]C}]
         ...
         code
         ...
      \end{lstlisting}
      \caption{Code-Beispiel}
      \label{Beispielcode_1}
   \end{code}
\start{document}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvUCO.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lhj0.png)

The first screenshot shows the problem (large gap).

The second screenshot shows how it should look, placement wise. But without the caption and directory working.

Thank you, to all the people that answer in advance. I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: Please add a compilable [mre]